# Installed dbt but getting error "DBT command not found error"

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, powershell-2.0, dbt

I would like to use `dbt` (Data build tool) in one of my project. I am facing hurdle while creating a project or using DBT command.

I have completed the installation process as described on DBT website given here: https://docs.getdbt.com/v0.10/docs/windows. DBT installed successfully but when I tried to use DBT command for creating project it gave me error:

> 'dbt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I am using windows 10, and I have tried it for python 3.6 as well as python 3.7 version.

any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Also check that Git for windows is installed. Check the link below for instructions. https://git-scm.com/downloads

Answer (score 5):

In order to execute `dbt` command you have to be in a folder with a *DBT Project*. Usually it doesn't work from anywhere.

Think that you can have multiple projects and `dbt run` will execute models on your current project.

Answer (score 2):

In my case forgetting to activate conda/python environment caused the issue. so try to activate the environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Create and activate a fresh virtual environment**

```bash
$ python3 -m venv dbt-venv
$ source dbt-venv/bin/activate
```

**Step 2: Install dbt-core and dbt adapter(s)**

```bash
pip install dbt-core
```

Depending on your target database or data warehouse, you'll have to install the corresponding adapter. For instance, for Google BigQuery:

```bash
pip install dbt-bigquery
```

And you should now be able to run any dbt command.

Answer (score 2):

on mac:

pip3 install dbt-bigquery, if problem persists you need to add the directory where the install happened to your path.

1. find the location of your dbt executable:
   echo $(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin
2. Add dir to path (e.g. zsh):
   vim ~/.zshrc
   export PATH=/Users/pmo511/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH
3. Apply change:
   source ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 1):

It means, either that the program is not installed, or that it can't be accessed from just anywhere. Therefore:

- Check if the installation has been done successfully, and where the program `dbt.*` (I believe it's `dbt.exe`) can be found.
- In case you've found the file, add the directory to the `PATH` environment variable of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following

1. Create environment

```
python3 -m venv dbt-env
```

2. Activate environment

```
dbt-env\Scripts\activate
```

3. Check the `dbt` has been installed correctly

```
dbt --version
```

This is based on the similar installation described in the [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/installation/#installation), although adjusted to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if you are inside the environment where you have installed DBT
2. Inside environment check dbt version using dbt --version
3. DBT works where you have created DBT project except for the command - ***dbt init <project_name>*** which is used to create a project. Once you have created project inside that you can use any DBT command.
4. If you can get version of DBT then you should be able to create project and use related commands
5. If you dont have profiles.yml configured, you will explicitly get error asking for that, in that case configure profiles file using DBT documentation.
6. Even after creating DBT project you can get errors due to many reasons, which has to be sorted out, but if you are able to run command dbt run -m <model_name.sql> you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

`dbt` command needs `dbt_project.yml` to define model paths and test paths
and initiate vars and so on....
And `dbt` gets the current directory as the default path, you can get dir using `pwd` command


But if you have many projects or want to run `dbt` from any directory, You need to pass env `project-dir` that path must have a `dbt_project.yml`

```
dbt run --project-dir <project path>
```

And likewise, if you have many dbt profiles, You can specify any one for execution with using env `profiles-dir`

```
dbt run --profiles-dir <profile path>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope you have run **pip install dbt-snowflake** or any other database specific run.
2. You need to check **python --version** and **pip list** to confirm python path is correctly set and dbt library is installed.
3. You can run command **dbt init --profiles-dir <directory/folder where you want to have profile file>**.
4. Better to
   set environment variable **DBT_PROFILES_DIR** with directory where you want to store your profile. Earlier dbt init was allowed to run without setting this environment variable.
5. It will keep asking profile directory for all commands now e.g. dbt init, dbt run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a virtual environment or locally? If you're installing dbt locally then you should be able to access the `dbt` command from anywhere in your command line.
E.g. `dbt --version` should give a result if you've installed locally, but if you're installing to a virtual environment then you'd need to spin that up first.

I'd install locally first to rule that out. ([https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/pip-install#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20use%20pip,environments%20when%20installing%20with%20pip%20.](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/pip-install#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20use%20pip,environments%20when%20installing%20with%20pip%20.))

Run `pip install dbt-core` in a fresh command line window then once it's finished and you've addressed any additional prompts, restart your command line then try `dbt --version` again.

Let us know how you get on!

Answer (score -1):

For dbt to work.

1. Set up database credentials in the `profiles.yml`
2. Run `dbt init [project_name]`
3. Go to the directory of the project you just created and run `dbt debug` this will return an output that shows whether your database credentials are in order and that dbt can connect to the database